# How does the javafx fxml method add active visible events to the current interface?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

There is a tabPane tab, which has two panels, A and B, which are created by fxml. When the program starts, it will call the initialize() method to initialize it. The function I will implement is placed in the method. But I can't realize my needs. The effect I want to achieve is that when the program is started, when I click interface B, an event is triggered, that is, the B interface. When the activation is visible, a certain method is executed.

```
public class TestLogPane extends AnchorPane implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
            webView.getEngine().load("https://wwww.xxx.com/member/login.jhtml");
            webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty()
                    .addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                        if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                            if (webView.getEngine().getLocation().contains("item.taobao.com")) {
                               System.out.println(webView.getEngine().getLocation());
                            }
                        }
                    });
    }

}

<TestLogPane fx:id="anchorPane" prefHeight="814.0" prefWidth="1414.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.fendo.huasheng.component.pane.TestLogPane">
   <children>
      <WebView fx:id="webView" prefHeight="814.0" prefWidth="1414.0" />
      <Button layoutX="1043.0" layoutY="22.0" onAction="#onGet" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Go" />
      <Button layoutX="980.0" layoutY="22.0" onAction="#onLoad" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Load" />
   </children>
</TestLogPane>
```

Tabpane fxml is defined as follows

```
<HomePane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
          fx:controller="com.fendo.huasheng.component.pane.HomePane"
          prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1024.0">
    <fx:define>
        <fx:include source="TestLogPane.fxml" fx:id="testLogPane" />
        <fx:include source="xxxx.fxml" fx:id="xxxx" />
    </fx:define>
    <children>
        <BorderPane prefHeight="750.0" prefWidth="900.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="2.0">
            <center>
                <TabPane prefHeight="750.0" prefWidth="757.0"  BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <tabs>
                        <Tab text="xxxx" content="$xxxx"></Tab>
                        <Tab text="Taobao" content="$testLogPane"></Tab>
                    </tabs>
                </TabPane>
            </center>
        </BorderPane>
    </children>
</HomePane>
```

Comment: Is that [onMouseClicked](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onMouseClickedProperty) what you need ?

Comment: This should not be what I need

Comment: Are you looking for [`TabPane.selectionModel`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TabPane.html#selectionModelProperty) or [`Tab.selected`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#selectedProperty)?